# Allow pulling from ECR ecr.dkr VPC Endpoint, but not pushing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecr, vpc-endpoint

It is possible to allow pulling from but not pushing to the Docker API VPC Endpoint (`com.amazonaws.<region>.ecr.dkr`) in its attached policy?

I can't find a reference for any supported actions other than `"*"`, is there a way to specify pull only? Or something via a condition?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can achieve this with a VPC endpoint policy.

Here's an example from the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints.html). This policy enables a specific IAM role to pull images from Amazon ECR:

```
{
    "Statement": [{
        "Sid": "AllowPull",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/role_name"
        },
        "Action": [
            "ecr:BatchGetImage",
            "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
            "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "*"
    }]
}
```

Comment: That is using the AWS API, `com.amazonaws.<region>.ecr.api`

Comment: @OJFord why do you think that?

Comment: @OJFord have you tried creating an ecr.drk endpoint and attaching this policy?

Comment: Well, for one thing those actions _are_ AWS APIs? I tried something similar (more allowed actions) before I understood the distinction between ecr.api/ecr.dkr and just applied the same to both. I can only get roughly the restriction I want by conditioning on the `aws:PrincipalArn` and `aws:ResourceTag`.

Comment: As an aside: I found that `Principal: AWS: <role ARN>` doesn't work in VPCE policies btw; I've had to use the condition `ArnEquals` on `aws:PrincipalArn` as above instead.

Comment: @OJFord for `ecr.drk` the documentation I linked states: *This endpoint is used for the Docker Registry APIs. Docker client commands such as push and pull use this endpoint.*

Comment: @OJFord I created an `ecr.drk` endpoint and then modified it to have this policy and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In AWS Console, add security groups that your instances (maybe all possible security groups) are using to the VPC endpoints.